# Have issue while saving activity_main.xml

Tags: android

I have created the android application project but if i try to save the "activity_main.xml" it is saying that.

**Message**

The original file 'activity_main.xml' has been deleted or is not accessible.

If I click ok it is trying to replace the xml. But it did not happen before. I am using eclipse.

If I create any other activity and try to save that xml then it is working fine. This error is happening only for launcher activity with the project name FCI.

It works fine if I change the project name.

Comment: So the file probably just got corrupted somehow. Why not try to just copy everything in it so you don't lose that, completely delete the old file and just create a new one and paste the old contents?

Comment: I tried creating the new project it is happening even with the default files which will be created while creating new project.

Comment: This might sound weird but an acquiantanc of mine ran into a similar problem. He solved it by removing the *underscore* from the file name, i.e. rename it to activitymain.xml and it solved it for him. You could give it a try too.

Comment: Cheers swayam, i'm on a mac and removing the underscore worked for me :D

Comment: hi restart your eclipse...

Answer (score 3):

This issue occurs to me every time I delete a project from a workspace, and then import one with the same name from another location. (Using `eclipse Kepler sr 2`)

I guess eclipse caches the workspace session metadata, but doesn't update it on such overwrites.

Restarting the workbench solves this problem every time.

Comment: Thanks..I am facing this issue because of the same reason i guess..what do you mean by restarting the workbench?

Comment: @Giri either `File --> Restart`, or simply close eclipse and start it again.

Comment: sorry..it did not help..I resolved it by changing the workspace location or created project with some other name.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to restart your eclipse... I hope it would work for you